# google map is showing plain page with marker in swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I have created new project and followed all this instructions from [this link](https://www.simplifiedios.net/google-maps-ios-tutorial/)

but my output is getting like this.
[the stimulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkRhw.png)

I dont know where I have missed.Can anyone help me with this please..

well this is my code

1. Appdelegate.swift

   ```
   var window: UIWindow?
   let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"


   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       FirebaseApp.configure()
       Messaging.messaging().delegate = self as! MessagingDelegate
       UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
       let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
       UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions) { (_, error) in
           guard error == nil else{
               print(error!.localizedDescription)
               return
           } }
       InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
           if let error = error {
               print("Error fetching remote instance ID: \(error)")
           } else if let result = result {
               print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
           }
       }

       application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
       //GOOGLE MAPS API
       GMSServices.provideAPIKey("KEY")
       return true
   }
   ```
2. My View controller.swift

   ```
       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
           //super.tabBarController?.title = "Contact Us"

           //creating a camera
           let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 23.431351, longitude: 85.325879, zoom: 6.0)

           //this is our map view
           let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)

           //adding mapview to view
           view = mapView

           //creating a marker on the map
           let marker = GMSMarker()
           marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 23.431351, longitude: 85.325879)
           marker.title = "ADDRESS"
           marker.map = mapView
       }
   ```

Comment: post your code here or wait for sometime it seems like your simulator is not loaded properly

Comment: Try to zoomOut, actually sometime map display on very low level camera position. You need to set camera zoom in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @Wings its the same code thats in the link dear

Comment: @SagarChauhan I zoomed out but it did not helo and I dont think its camera problem because I wrote the same code that the editor used in that link

Comment: @DeepthiSareddy...did you get the key from google console??

Comment: @Wings ofcourse I did and its also been restricted

Comment: Can you put your code on GitHub so I can see

Comment: @Wings check the edit please

Comment: your code looks good just check in storyboard that you created the outlet of `GMSMapView`

Comment: @Wings  Yes my view is GMSMapView, then also it is the same

Comment: I have got it, I forgot to Enable Api

Comment: @DeepthiSareddy...Great :)

Comment: you were reallly helpful tho :) @Wings